# How can I develop a Google Chrome extension without constantly repacking it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I remember reading about a way to develop a Google Chrome extension without constantly repacking it. In Firefox this is done by creating a soft link between the extensions directory and where your development directory is. I've forgotten the method to do this with Google Chrome and can't seem to find it when searching.

Also, if you know the answer to this question you've probably done some Chrome extension development, so I'll ask (as a bonus), **what are the most valuable tools for developing a chrome extension - the ones that just make your life so much easier?**

ps: The developer tools look nice. How can I log things inside a script (console.log?) and where do I see that output? Doesn't seem to be showing up here:

[image: Picture.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable `developer mode` on chrome://settings/extensions and hit `load unpacked extension`.

The most valuable tool for me is the build in [developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html).

Comment: very nice. thank you. where do i see the output from `console.log()` in the developer tools?

Comment: From Console ;) Right click on webpage, Inspert element, from top row Console.

Comment: @BadrHari - Even if console.log() was called inside the extension? Or is there another console function I should use inside the extension? Thanks :)

Comment: Extension pages (including the background page) will be listed under the unpacked extension (you may need to expand it with the triangle). If you click on one the developer tools for it will open, allowing you to see console output.